# Python Selenium Firefox Firebug export .har-file

Tags: python, selenium, har

I`m exporting a .har file using firebug extension for webdriver firefox in python selenium. I can get the "DomContentLoaded" and "'load' (event) but is it possible to get the Total time needed for all requests to be finished? Look at the attachment. It says 3.8 sec is total time for all requests, and 2s is the load event which is in my .har-file

[image]

I think it might be possible to add all the times for each entry, but I hope for a better solution.

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the entire code?

Comment: I did not find a good solution for this, but I resolved it by looping through all entries in the .HAR file, and getting the starteddatetime for each of them. I saved the max and min datetime, and the total response time is (max-min)